# Isolation Forest - Cost function and optimization method

Tags: machine-learning, cart, loss-functions, anomaly-detection, isolation-forest

I have two questions about isolation forest. I may not understand how it works correctly but I just wonder:

1. What is the cost function of the isolation forest?
2. What is the optimization method to minimize such a loss function?

I read the original paper and was looking for an answer in other sources but I could not find any answer. I just found that decision tree uses a MSE as a cost function while isolation free is based on randomization.

Answer (score 1):

Same as [with regular decision tree](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/488194/how-gradient-descent-is-used-for-classification-with-decision-trees/488303#488303), isolation forest is *not* trained by directly minimizing some loss, but by using a dedicated algorithm. If you are interested in the algorithm, check the paper by it's authors, where they describe it in detail:

> Liu, Fei Tony, Ting, Kai Ming and Zhou, Zhi-Hua. (2008). [“Isolation
> forest.”](https://cs.nju.edu.cn/zhouzh/zhouzh.files/publication/icdm08b.pdf) Data Mining. ICDM’08.

Comment: Thanks @Tim for your clarification. Yes, I may need to go through the paper again.