# I want to formulate mathematically the k-nn, objective function and neighborhood

Tags: machine-learning, k-nearest-neighbour

**Summary** : I need help to write the mathematical formulation of the objective function of knn and relate it to the neighborhood definition.
The definition should encorporate the demonstration of the online evaluation objective and optionally the formulation of additional hashing algorithms (eg ScanNN).

**Problem:**
Given  distance of choice eg minkowski: $d(\hat{x}, {x})$
The neighborhood of $k$  samples for the new sample $\hat{x}$, can be defined as  $N_k(\hat{x}, \{x\})$.
I want to express the creation of this neighborhood set as a function of  the distance.
But I am not sure how one can "create  a set" in mathematics language.

This is what I have so far :
[image]

Linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65334702/edit

Answer (score 1):

What about the following for a list of points $P = (p_1, \ldots, p_n)$:

> Let $d_i = ||x-p_i||$. Then the kNN neighbors of $x$ are
> $$\mbox{kNN}(x) = \{ p\in P \mbox{ with } ||p-x|| \leq rank_k(d_1,\ldots,d_n)\}$$
> where $rank_k$ means the $k$-th element in the ordered list (*nth_element* in C++ STL lingo).

Comment: Please can you help me elaborate on the rank_k structure? 
I think it captures the problems in a nice way. 
Alternatively if you know some good text book reference  it woudl be highly appreciated

Comment: $rank_k$ means the k-th element in the ordered list. It is not necessary, though, to actually order the entire list (an $O(n\log n)$ algorithm) to obtain the k-th element. It is possible to compute the k-th element in $O(n)$ runtime: such an efficient implementation is readily available in the C++ STL algorithm nth_element: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stdnth_element-in-cpp/

Comment: I understand but outsdie of Cpp in pure mathi is there such a thing as orderderd set ?

Comment: No, sets are unordered. "Ordered sets" are called "lists". Unlike sets, lists can also have duplicate entries. Just to complete the terminology: there is also a mathematical structure that represents sets (unordered), but that can have duplicate entries. It is called "bags" or (sometimes) "multisets".

Comment: Lets use max_k then to replace rank_k in the solution what do you think ?

Comment: Just saw your edit suggestion, but it does not seem correct to me: there is no k-th element in a set (only in a list). Moreover, you confuse $\hat{x}$ with $x$ and you dropped the essential point that the $d_i$ must be sorted (ordered) $d_1\leq d_2\leq\ldots$.

Comment: max k is taking an unsorted set and output a sorted set. 
By applying max k times and removing the item we accomplish the knn task I think.